# Websphere to Jboss migration

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I need to migrate one of my application from Websphere(6.1) to JBoss (EAP 5.1) . Application is now using the following code to get the WebsphereTransactionManager object and perform suspend and resume operations

com.ibm.ws.Transaction.WebSphereTransactionManager  txMgr = com.ibm.ws.Transaction.TransactionManagerFactory.getTransactionManager();
javax.transaction.Transaction thisTx = null;

thisTx = txMgr.suspend();

// Code to do non transactional operations

txMgr.resume(thisTx);

How could I get a TransactionManager Object in Jboss? Any sample code please?

Comment: Now I got an option to get the JBoss TransactionManager in my java code. `TransactionManager transactionManager = (TransactionManager) initialContext.lookup("java:/TransactionManager");`

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage JBoss Windup (http://windup.jboss.org) to help you with this and other migration questions.  Just run Windup on your source or archive.  Check out the videos under Guides section for more help.