# how to migrate from websphere to jboss ? what major configurations need to be changed?

Tags: jboss, migration, websphere

How do I migrate from Websphere to Jboss ?

Need to deploy a java application hosted in websphere to jboss.

(P.S : without using Maven build)

Comment: also partly answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767550/websphere-to-jboss-migration

Answer (score 1):

hi there are many guides on the developer forums for JBoss and there is also now a migration center.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebSphere+to+AS+7

http://www.jboss.org/migration/discover/

key concepts are the modular module system where you will need to create modules for database drivers eg Oracle. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreateAModuleForOracleDatasourceInJBoss711Final

using the Manifest in your deployments or create JBoss deployment structure XML files to create dependencies on modules created above or Java EE etc.

also the standalone XML files contain the server configuration. there are several different types out of the box depending if you want to run in a cluster, etc.

all the operations use see in the admin web interface are available via the management CLI. see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+Clients

i hope this helps.